# Continuous function in 2D

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, vector-spaces, plane-geometry

$f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ is a continuous function. $x,y\in\mathbb R^2$.

Define $\overline{xy}$ as the segment connecting the points $x,y$, excluding the end points.

> Given: $f(x)>f(z)$ for all $z\in\overline{xy}$.
>
> Can we claim that, there exists a neighborhood open set $S$ of $x$, such that for any $x'$ in the set $S$, we have $f(x')>f(z')$, for any $z'\in\overline{x'y}$?

By the definition of continuity, it is obvious that for any $a\in\overline{xy}$, there exists an open epsilon ball $B_\epsilon(x)$ and $B_\epsilon(a)$, such that for any $x'\in B_\epsilon(x)$ and $a'\in B_\epsilon(a)$, we have $f(x')>f(a')$

However, the difficulty is, when $a$ is moving from $y$ to $x$, the $\epsilon\to 0$

I don't know how to get over this. Would be very grateful if you could help. Are there any named theorems on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Consider $g:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R:t\mapsto f((1-t)x+ty).$

Comment: I am truly sorry that I misunderstood the problem. I need to show that there exists an open ball around $x$, such that for all $x'$ in that ball, we have $f(x')>f(\overline{x'y})$. Finding one $x'$ is not sufficient.

Comment: Then the claim is false: take $f(x,y)=x^2-y^2,\ \vec x=(0,0), \vec y=(0,1).$.

Comment: You are right. I must rethink about it